# SplashScreen/Jdialog is not in center anymore in java9

Tags: java, splash-screen, java-9

I just switched to java 9 from java 8. I am using following code to build a splash screen. Splash screen comes in the center of the monitor if I use java 8, but with java 9 its not in center. Any idea, what can I do?

```
public void showSplashScreen() throws MalformedURLException
{
    dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setModal(false);
    dialog.setUndecorated(true);
    dialog.getRootPane().setOpaque(false);
    dialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

    URL imageURL = SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/" + fImage);
    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageURL));
    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    dialog.add(background);
    String versionInfo = readVersion();
    JLabel text = new JLabel(versionInfo);
    text.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(240, 272, 150, 50));
    background.add(text);

    progressBar.setMaximum(PROGBAR_MAX);
    dialog.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    startProgressBar();

    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Why don’t you use the [builtin splash screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/awt/SplashScreen.html) feature? It has the advantage of being shown much earlier during startup.

Comment: My current code is working fine with the ability of putting dynamic text at certain location on the screen.

Comment: The builtin splash screen also allows drawing on it.

Comment: I figured, dialog.setUndecorated(true); dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)); are causing the issue. Dont know why, but having them in my code cause the issue. But I need them to make the transparent background.